# HLS audio is choppy on Safary, but good on other major browsers

Tags: javascript, audio, video, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have three HTML5 media tags. One video and two audios. I stream them by HLS. I have the following code for the HLS setup.

The audios are good on major browsers except Safari. Audios are choppy for Safari on both macOS and iOS. I wonder if I'm missing something setting up HLS?

```html
<video id="vid" preload="metadata" muted playsinline></video>
<audio id="human" preload="metadata" playsinline></audio>
<audio id="racoon" preload="metadata" playsinline></audio>

<script>
    // HLS setup for media.
    var media = document.getElementById('vid');
    var mediaSrc = 'media/vid/playlist.m3u8';
    // First check for native browser HLS support
    if (media.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
      media.src = mediaSrc;
      // If no native HLS support, check if HLS.js is supported
    } else if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      var hls = new Hls();
      hls.loadSource(mediaSrc);
      hls.attachMedia(media);
    } else {
      // Alert only once. Don't alert for other video/audio tags.
      alert("Your browser doesn't support HTTP Live Streaming.")
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    // HLS setup for media.
    var media = document.getElementById('human');
    var mediaSrc = 'media/human/playlist.m3u8';
    // First check for native browser HLS support
    if (media.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
      media.src = mediaSrc;
      // If no native HLS support, check if HLS.js is supported
    } else if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      var hls = new Hls();
      hls.loadSource(mediaSrc);
      hls.attachMedia(media);
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    // HLS setup for media.
    var media = document.getElementById('racoon');
    var mediaSrc = 'media/racoon/playlist.m3u8';
    // First check for native browser HLS support
    if (media.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
      media.src = mediaSrc;
      // If no native HLS support, check if HLS.js is supported
    } else if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      var hls = new Hls();
      hls.loadSource(mediaSrc);
      hls.attachMedia(media);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "choppy"?  Got a recording?  It isn't going to have anything to do with your code here, since all you're doing is setting the `src`.  Might have something to do with the encoded audio maybe, but could be something else entirely.  What's the source sample rate?

Comment: @Brad The audios are recorded by a 48KHz sample rate. What I'm suspicious of, is the fact that on the server-side I'm preparing one video and two audios with the same [FFmpeg script](https://gist.github.com/mrbar42/ae111731906f958b396f30906004b3fa).

Comment: @Brad By *choppy* I mean the audios are not continuous. They get interrupted frequently.

Comment: Can you post a recording?  Are they interrupted at perfectly regular intervals?  Is the pitch correct?  There's nothing here to help you, sorry.  Post more information and a recording.  The problem isn't your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had three HTML media tags, one video and two audios:

```html
    <video id="vid" preload="metadata" muted playsinline>
      <source src="media/vid/playlist.m3u8">
      <source src="media/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="media/vid.mov" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="media/vid.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="media/vid.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the vedio tag.
    </video>

    <audio id="human" preload="metadata" playsinline>
      <source src="media/human/playlist.m3u8">
      <source src="media/human.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="media/human.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="media/human.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>
 
    <audio id="racoon" preload="metadata" playsinline>
      <source src="media/racoon/playlist.m3u8">
      <source src="media/racoon.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="media/racoon.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="media/racoon.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>
```

I was getting the media elements:

```js
      var vid = document.getElementById("vid")
      var audioHuman = document.getElementById("human")
      var audioRaccoon = document.getElementById("racoon")
```

Then, I was using a callback for video play:

```js
      // When video is playing, move slider and play audio.
      vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate)
```

The callback updates the audio current time according to the video:

```js
    function timeUpdate() {
      t = vid.currentTime
     

        // Human voice isn't synced with video. It was a recording mistake.
        // Compensate for the mistake.
        var audioHumanOffset = 1.4
 
        audioHuman.currentTime = t - audioHumanOffset
        audioRaccoon.currentTime = t
      

    }
```

The above callback was the cause of bad audio on Safari. After removing the above callback, the Safar audio is good now =)

The above callback is replaced by a totally different logic to keep video and audios in sync.

Comment: What was your sync solution, if you don't mind me asking? Also, is the solution solid/stable?

Comment: @MustafaM Happy to help. I don't remember the sync solution at the time. But eventually, we used this reliable repository: https://github.com/naomiaro/waveform-playlist